# Custom Fields Question

Tags: custom-field, customization, links, template-tags, icon

I'm new to wordpress and I am trying to understand these custom fields. I read the wordpress codex page refering to custom fields but I have some questions.
I take for example my site. I created a custom field named "country_flag". I want this custom field to store for every post a link to a icon displaying a country flag.

This icon i want to place on my site after the post title to show guest in which language the post is.

On the codex page it tells me to place `<?php the_meta(); ?>` in my template. But if i have more custom fields and I want only one to be shown in my template where i put the `<?php the_meta(); ?>`, what code should I place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display a single custom field (post meta) then you can use:

```
get_post_meta();
```

It has three arguments.

1. The ID of the post
2. The name of the post meta field (country_flag)
3. Whether or not the value returned is a single string (in your case it will be);

So the usage might be something like this:

```
$country_flag = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'country', true );
```

Comment: I should add the `$country_flag = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'country', true );` in single.php after `<?php the_title(); ?> ` to display the custom field after title of the post?

Comment: <?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'country', true ); ?>

Comment: Very nice!Thanks alot! One final question.
If i want to display the flag in the home screen after the views,comment and likes icons like in this image
http://s15.postimg.org/pe9dae4fv/cacat.png?
The theme is detube. I just need to put the code in the template file just like I did with the one in the title?

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself? Then, if you can't get it working update your code. Also upvote the answer if you found it helpful.